# Can't restore Service Master Key to developer edition, but can to localdb

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2019

I need to restore the service master key from a server to my local database.  This is working on SQL Server Express's `(localdb)\msSqlLocalDB` database, but it's not working on the SQL Server Developer edition on the same machine.

I use this SQL statement to restore the key:

```
ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY REGENERATE 
GO

RESTORE SERVICE MASTER KEY 
FROM FILE = N'\\exported_servicemasterkey' 
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'my_password'
FORCE
GO
```

I get an error from the restore step:

> Msg 15317, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
> The master key file does not exist or has invalid format.

I am sure the file is there, and the format is correct.  It's working on localDB.

- LocalDB is version 15.0.2000.
- Developer edition is 15.0.2000.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exported_servicemasterkey file in the original question is a network location.  Apparently, the account running localDB (NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS) has access to this location.  The account running developer edition (NT Service\MSSQLSERVER) do not have access to the location.
I coped the file from the network location to my drive. The restore worked after this.